# How to avoid an extra trailing newline when using Scala's sys.process to shell out

Tags: scala

I need to execute an external binary from my Scala code and get its output.  The standard way to do this seems to be using [scala.sys.process](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/sys/process/package.html).  The following code mostly works:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val command = Seq("python3", "-c", "print('foo', end='')")
val result = command.!!
```

However, it seems like there is an extra trailing newline:

```
print(result.length) // prints 4 instead of 3
print(result) // prints an extra newline at the end
```

I can just modify the result string to remove the last character, but it seems weird that sys.process would add a trailing newline to output, so I thought it might either be a bug with what I'm doing or something that can be configured.

Is the trailing newline supposed to be there?

Is there a way to get rid of it without manipulating the output string?

Comment: I want to avoid doing a `.trim` because the real binary can output arbitrary strings, potentially including whitespace at the end, and I want to preserve exactly what it outputs.

Comment: Added a bounty to this, as I'm really curious as well. Until then, I found a haskish workaround-- pipe the output of command you're using through a base64 encoder, and then trim and base64 decode the string that is returned to the Scala layer.

Hackish, but fully preserves the state of stdout (with or without a trailing newline) when it's piped through `base64`.

Comment: @Nathan; I don't quite see how that would work, but if it does then you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I think @jwvh is perfect, maybe this additional info could help :

Newline is actually a system property, so you can set it to be blank by launching your app with the option `-Dline.separator=""` I'm not sure I'd recommend it though. 

Alternatively, you can reflect on the Newline value in BasicIO before and after your method call to modify it and empty its value only for your process.!! call.

Comment: @Nathan; Now that the bounty is past, I'm curious how my 2nd answer (the one with zero votes) fell short of your expectations.

Comment: @jwvh It didn't; I actually assigned the bounty to it at one point, but my connection had just died so it didn't actually send, and I forgot about it after. My bad. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `val result = cmd.lineStream`?  (Or the related `.lineStream_!`, which offers some protection against exceptions.)

The result is a `Stream[String]`.  Each element of the stream is a string of output from the process with whitespace preserved but there are no newline characters because that's the stream element delimiter.

---

The added newline appears to be intentional for processes launched with `!!`.

In [ProcessBuilderImpl.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.6/src/library/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilderImpl.scala):

```
def !! = slurp(None, withIn = false)
```

...

```
private[this] def slurp(log: Option[ProcessLogger], withIn: Boolean): String = {
  val buffer = new StringBuffer
  val code   = this ! BasicIO(withIn, buffer, log)

  if (code == 0) buffer.toString
  else scala.sys.error("Nonzero exit value: " + code)
}
```

In [BasicIO.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.6/src/library/scala/sys/process/BasicIO.scala):

```
def apply(withIn: Boolean, buffer: StringBuffer, log: Option[ProcessLogger]) =
    new ProcessIO(input(withIn), processFully(buffer), getErr(log))
```

...

```
def processFully(buffer: Appendable): InputStream => Unit =
  processFully(appendLine(buffer))
```

...

```
private[this] def appendLine(buffer: Appendable): String => Unit = line => {
    buffer append line
    buffer append Newline  <--!!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`sys.process` *isn't* adding the trailing newline: `echo` is. From the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo):

> DESCRIPTION
>        The echo utility writes any specified operands, separated by single blank (`') characters and followed by a newline (`\n')
>   character, to the standard output.

Using `trim` can remove this. Otherwise, you can do this, if your shell supports it:

`val result = "echo -n foo".!!`

Comment: You're right -- echo was adding a newline in that case.  However, the real binary I'm dealing with doesn't output a newline at the end.  Updating the example now to fix that bug.

Answer (score 1):

In order to preserve the output as presented, you have to intercept the `InputStream` before any NewLine interpretations (or additions).

```
import sys.process._

val cmnd = Seq("/bin/echo","-n","one\n\nthree")

val stdOutBuf = new StringBuilder
val pio = new ProcessIO(_.close()  //ignore STDIN
  ,out=>{                          //save STDOUT
    val src = io.Source.fromInputStream(out)
    src.foreach(stdOutBuf.+=)
    src.close()
  },_.close())                     //ignore STDERR (or not, up to you)

val exitCode :Int = cmnd.run(pio).exitValue()
val exactOutput :String = stdOutBuf.result()
```